# Delphi, TIBDatabase, Sharing connection by Handle

Tags: database, delphi, dll, firebird, handle

I have a little problem. I want to move app and dll with DelphiXE2 it DelphiXE10. The connection to the database from EXE to DLL passes through the Handle (SetHandle (Rec.DBHandle)). Everything worked well under DelphiXE2. Once compiled EXE and DLL under DelphiXE10 error occurs when calling such IBQuery.Open. Has anyone encountered a similar problem.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What **exact** error message do you get?  Readers shouldn't have to guess.

Comment: Error message : Raised exception class $C0000005 with message "access violation at 0x08c61113: read of adress 0x00000000".

Comment: I noticed that the closing connection in a DLL (IBDataBase.Close) and opening again (IBDataBase.Open) after assigning Handle makes IBQuery.Open working properly.
But such a solution is inappropriate.

Comment: Was IBX in XE10 fixed to load proper client library? my blind shot would be that XE2-IBX uses legacy stub GDS32.DLL (and that is a sure thing, unless patched by TS) and then XE10 uses proper FbClient.DLL instead. So, handle of one firebird client DLL does not apply to another. Personally I would use something like SysInternals Process Explorer or Process Monitor to check that both XE2-EXE and XE10-DLL use one and the same DLL, with same name from same folder path. And also i'd ditch IBX and use some FB-aware lib....

Comment: "opening again" would just make new handle....

Comment: Are you EXE and DLL compiled with the same Delphi version ? If it does, just drop DLL and use BPL instead. Then you would share the very `IBDatabase` object, not a handler

Comment: EXE is also compiled into XE10

Comment: I was thinking about BPL, but at the moment such a solution is impossible.